# How is the location of a subView set?

Tags: iphone, facebook, addsubview

I am using the standard facebook connect button with the method

```
FBLoginButton *loginButton = [[[FBLoginButton alloc] init] autorelease];
[self.view addSubview: loginButton];
```

and It places it where I dont want it. How can I set that subviews location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access the view's `frame` property:

```
loginButton.frame = CGRectMake(originX, originY, sizeWidth, sizeHeight);
```

Answer (score 2):

You set a view's origin relative to their parent view using `setFrameOrigin:`

```
NSPoint origin = NSMakePoint(0,0);
FBLoginButton *loginButton = [[[FBLoginButton alloc] init] autorelease];
[loginButton setFrameOrigin:origin];
[self.view addSubview: loginButton];
```

Answer (score 0):

Like every other UIView, you can use its frame property to specify its size and position.

You can also use the center property to just reposition the control.